# Как заставить бота отвечать на команды после того как он написал первым. aiogram

Tags: telegram, aiogram

Мой код выглядит вот так

```
@dp.chat_join_request_handler()
async def join(update: types.ChatJoinRequest):
    await bot.send_message(update.from_user.id, 'Реклама')
    await update.approve()
```

И если я добавляют:

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
```

бот не видит этой команды

Comment: извините непонятно

Answer (score 0):

Такое может быть только по одной причине - если какой-то другой хендлер успел "словить" месседж, то он просто не дойдёт до того, что ниже. Проверь, чтобы у тебя не было пустого хендлера выше по типу:

```py
@dp.message_handler()
```

Ну или любого другого, который может перехватить это сообщение\

Comment: не было, это весь код) я написал на aiograme 3 написал и все работает